# Sharing Text File using ACTION_SEND

Tags: android

We can open share dialog using ACTION_SEND   to share text

```
     Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Download Link: Android play store link");
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share This App"));
```

How can I use ACTION_SEND  to share  a text file.

I read  http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html   but could not get how to share text file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the following line.

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
    emailIntent.setType("*/*");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"me@gmail.com"}); 
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, 
    "Test Subject"); 
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, 
    "go on read the emails");     
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromfile(new File(yourtextfilepath));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

Make sure that your text file path should be from external memory card. Action send wont accept the files from internal memory.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This won't work accross different profiles. You should share content with a ContentProvider instead http://developer.android.com/training/enterprise/app-compatibility.html#sharing_files

Comment: ... Uri.fromfile( ...  syntax is wrong, change it to Uri.fromFile(

Comment: This is the cleanest and simpliest way that I found after several attems and others Examples. My case: My app creates a .csv file and stores it in the DOWNLOAD folder, and i Want share it after the file is created without use of the FileProvider.

Comment: But, can't we share a text file to other apps without using the email route? This looks like it gets intercepted by mail apps only.