# How to share *.txt file in android

Tags: android, android-file, android-sharing

I tried many ways but I can't do this.

I have a ***.txt** file. I want to share it via `Bluetooth, wifi, email and ...`.

When i used this code i cant share the file:

```
  File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Email-Ghap/Emails.txt");
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("*/txt");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, file);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "share file with"));
```

Totally I want this: when the user clicked on the share button and chooses one email sender like **Gmail** for sharing. the file must be attached file for the new email ...

I found this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/16036249/4016922

But it shares txt file content. I want to share the file not the content of the txt file

Comment: Try with this links :
sharing pDF file you can change with .txt http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17985646/android-sharing-files-by-sending-them-via-email-or-other-apps

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change your Code Like this.

From

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Email-Ghap/Emails.txt");
```

To

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "Email-Ghap/Emails.txt");
```

from:

```
sharingIntent.setType("*/txt");
```

To

```
sharingIntent.setType("text/*");
```

so yourFinal Code Looks Like

```
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + "abc.txt");
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/*");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + file.getAbsolutePath()));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "share file with"));
```

Comment: Thanks, but this can not send file . the Bluetooth and other methods of sharing is appear but when i choose them to send Nothing happens .

Comment: When i use this `File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "Email-Ghap/Emails.txt");` i print `file` in log . its not true address .  i think my way to find path is true : `File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Email-Ghap/Emails.txt");`

Comment: actually from same code I was able to send my file.

Comment: are you sending a `*.txt` file ? can you send to `Bluetooth` successfully ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137118/discussion-between-janki-and-abbas-nikzad).

Comment: Uri.parse gives an error on "parse" as called the error: error: cannot find symbol method parse(String) what should I do?